# How to change index and value of array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this Javascript Object as below format but I want to convert it to another format as below:
I've pass value form let data = $('#clientForm').serializeArray();
Original format

```
 let data = $('#clientForm').serializeArray();
 { name="addr_types",  value="RESID"}
```

Wanted Format

```
 {addr_types:"RESID"}
```

Or another format

```
 {"addr_types":"RESID"}
```

[image]

Comment: None of your examples are proper objects. Perhaps you meant `{ name:"addr_types",  value:"RESID"}` You can have `{"addr_types":"RESID"}`

Comment: there are no variables/object in js name=value

Comment: I've confused now edited

Comment: and the first "object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your original object is a correct one

```js
var original = {
  name: "addr_types",
  value: "RESID"
};

console.log(original);

var newName = original.name;
var newValue = original.value;

var newObject = {};

newObject[newName] = newValue;

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: Object { name="addr_types",  value="WORK"}

Comment: No I  upvoded not me

Comment: @HengSopheak Ok but I still not understand your comment :)

Comment: Both answers (as of now) are correct. Nina's is more complete but this was answered in the same minute and is also correct.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a valid object, you could just assign the wanted property with the given key/value pair.

```js
var source = { name: "addr_types", value: "RESID" },
    target = {};

target[source.name] = source.value;

console.log(target);
```

ES6 with computed property

```js
var source = { name: "addr_types", value: "RESID" },
    target = { [source.name]: source.value };

console.log(target);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it using `.map()` function. bellow is the example.

```
var original = [{
  name: "addr_types",
  value: "Work"
},{
  name: "village",
  value: "Vang Tobang"
},{
  name: "commune",
  value: "Tang Krasang"
},{
  name: "destric",
  value: ""
},{
  name: "city",
  value: "Com Pong Thom"
},{
  name: "country",
  value: "combodia"
},
];

newArray = original.map(function(item){
             return {[item.name]: item.value}
           });
```

If your data container is not array then you can simply create as like bellow.

```
newArray = [original].map(function(item){
         return {[item.name]: item.value}
       });
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzrngch6/) link: https://jsfiddle.net/kzrngch6/